# POST Method not Capturing Data from Fields -- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am attempting to submit a form of JSON data, utilizing angularJS, nodeJS, and JS. However, on submission the form does not capture the body data and send it to the postgres db. I know that the record is updating in the db, as I have a field "updatedAt" that changes time stamp to recent time stamp on update. I have tried grouping everything together in an updateform model, but that does not help and also hinders the displaying of data from the record on an html page. I am not sure why angular is not capturing the form data and sending it. 
Here is the html with angularJS snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html > 
<html ng-app = "todo">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
            <form ng-submit="updateTodo(updateform)" role="form" ng-init="updateform = {}">
                <div class="datagrid">
                    <table> 
                        <thead> 
                            <tr> 
                                <th> ID </th>
                                <th> Name </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:{id:todoId} | orderBy:'id' | limitTo: 1 track by $index">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" ng-model="updateform.id" ng-init="updateform.id = todo.id">
                                    {{todo.id}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.todo" type="text"  value="{{todo.owner}}" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit"><strong>Update</strong></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

From observing network, the body response is not taking any of data from the form; to which I am at a slight loss. I have tried rewriting this with different schemas, but to no avail.
UPDATE:
Here is snippet of JS model for updatetodo and updateform:

```
$scope.updateform = {
    Name: '',

};
$scope.updateTodo = function() {
     $http.post('/todoupdate/'+$scope.todoId, {
        name: $scope.updateformName

    }).success(function (data,status, headers, config) {
        $scope.todos.push({
           name: $scope.updateformName

        });
    }).error(function (data,status, headers, congif) {
        console.log("whoopsies: "+ data)
    });
};
```

Here is nodeJS snippet:

```
exports.updatetodos = function (req, res) {
models.Todo.find({
where: {
  id: req.params.id
}
}).then(function(todo) {
if(todo) { // if the record exists in the db    
  todo.updateAttributes({
    name: req.body.name,
  }).then(function(todos) {
    res.json(todos.dataValues);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("ops: " + error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'error' });
  });
  };
 });
};
```

Comment: Show your updateTodo function as well, without it can't see what's going on really.  Also good to not use ng-init unless you're aliasing a ng-repeat special variable like $even or $last (instead initialize variables in a controller or a provider).

Comment: @JohnathanMackney please have a look on this fiddle it shows the way http://jsfiddle.net/p9voyyqo/

Comment: I have tried to reformat after this example, by taking updatefrom out and renaming such as `name="todo.name"`; but still has not changed